# QLPreviewController and NSFetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath returning nil

Tags: ios, qlpreviewcontroller

This code works at first touch. Preview starts to display (Title, Done, Actions, and blank page) and then `previewController:(QLPreviewController *)previewController previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index` is called again. This time `[self.resultsController objectAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];` returns nil - My guess is the entry is no longer selected. `index` is correct at 1.

**The procedure**:

```
- (id)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)previewController previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    Manuals *manuals = [self.resultsController objectAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];
    NSURL *vUrl = [self locateUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:manuals.Url] ofType:[manuals.Url pathExtension]];    
    return vUrl;
}
```

If I ignore the exception - the preview continues to display the the document.

I did try to keep the last good returned selectedIndexPath, but then received the error: `-[__NSArrayM indexAtPosition:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cd52800`

**The question**:

How can I get my resultsController object using only the passed in index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in `numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController:previewController`. I *was* returning the `[resultsController count]`, not the number of documents I wanted to be previewed. When the previewController tried to access the next few objects, it was returning nil.

```
// Returns the number of items that the preview controller should preview
- (NSInteger)numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController:(QLPreviewController *)previewController
{
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question but you can use:

```
[previewController setCurrentPreviewItemIndex:0];
```

to set the current item that you want to be previewed.

Comment: I am not calling [previewController in my code. It's delegated. I am just trying to return the correct file:// url the QLPreviewController is requesting.